# Can't assign to operator error

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I'm trying to make a simple guessing game as a school assignment. I started with a long version and am trying to make it shorter by using loops, but I'm getting a can't assign to operator error in line 13 which I don't understand while trying to perform the `A1 + 1 = A1`.

```
import sys
import random

A1 = 1
A2 = 2
A3 = 1
Array=[]
Len = int(input("How long do you what the game to be"))
for x in range(11):
G = random.randint(1,13)
Array.append(G)
for x in range(Len):
    A1 + 1 = A1
    A2 + 1 = A2
    A3 + 1 = A3
print(Array[A3])
Num = Array[A3]
G1 = input("Is the next number higher or lower.")
if Array[A1] - Array[A2] > 1:
    print("Correct")
    print("_______________________________________________________________________________")
else:
    print("YOu FaIl")
    print("_______________________________________________________________________________")
    sys.exit()
print("Well done you have won the game CONGRATS!")
```

Comment: I think you meant `A1 += 1`?

Comment: `A1 + 1 = A1` what in your understanding should happen here?

Comment: You've got to know about the assignment operator. Left side is assignee, right side is value to be assigned to assignee. Also, if you look at the code logically, how can you assign a constant (a number) to a different value?

Comment: BTW, you're going to get an index out of bounds error if the user enters a number greater than 11. I think you meant to do `for x in range(Len):`. And it's against the Python design guidelines to name variables with uppercase letters (e.g. `Array`).

Answer (score 3):

Assignment goes `<variable> = <expression>`, not the other way around.

This can be replaced

```
for x in range(Len):
   A1 + 1 = A1
   A2 + 1 = A2
   A3 + 1 = A3
```

By this (assuming you were wanting to add one to each of those variables `Len` times)

```
A1 += Len
A2 += Len
A3 += Len
```